# URL rewriting all pages into one page?

Tags: url-rewriting, iis-8

I'm trying to get all URLs except for a few to rewrite to `_main.php?url=/url/path/here` (the exceptions being a System, Frameworks, _Assets, or Administrator folder). I have a RegEx that does this matching for me: `(^|\n)(?!/?(?:_Assets|Administrator|Frameworks|System)).+` but I am not really understanding how to do this properly in IIS8. What it currently does is give me the correct data when I load the page, but it doesn't rewrite the URL, as seen in this image: [image: here]

My rule looks like this (with no conditions or variables):

[image: my inbound rewrite rule]

I was also trying to follow [this](http://www.domagojsalopek.com/Details/Introduction-to-URL-Rewriting-using-IIS-URL-Rewrite-Module-and-Regular-Expressions/26/CommentPage) guide, but it seemed like the exact opposite of what I wanted to achieve, and I don't know how to do the reverse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by changing the regexp to be `(^|\n)(?!_main.php\\?)(?!/?(?:_Assets|Administrator|Frameworks|System)).+` (ignoring _main.php) and then changing the rule to be a redirect instead of a rewrite, which achieved the desired effect.